# R Change NA values

Tags: r, na

My data looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXk8a.jpg

I want to change the values `NA` to another value for each column. 
For example in the column that contains `NA`, `Single` and `Dual`, I want to change all the `NA` to `'Single'`.

I tried this code:

```
data_price$nbrSims <- ifelse(is.na(data_price$nbrSims), 'Single', data_price$nbrSims)
```

But then my data looks like this, where `Dual` became `2` and `Single` `1`.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9oUw.jpg

How can I change the `NA` values, without changing the other values?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: don't post images of data. Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 16):

Try this (check which are `NA` and than replace them with `"Single"`):

```
data_price$nbrSims <- as.character(data_price$nbrSims)
data_price$nbrSims[is.na(data_price$nbrSims)] <- "Single"
```

Comment: This works after data_price$nbrSims <- as.character(data_price$nbrSims)

Comment: @GerritCalle, I've checked it and it should work without `as.character()`.

Comment: @GerritCalle is right: your solution _mostly_ doesn't work. It works only if `Single` is already a `level` of `data_price$nbrSims`. Just try `x<-factor(sample(c(NA,letters[1:4]),100,TRUE));x[is.na(x)]<-"Single"`. Better to convert to `character` beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I agree now.

Answer (score 5):

The reason why we got integer values 1 and 2 after the `ifelse` statement is because the column is a `factor` class.  We convert it to `character` class and it should work fine

```
 data_price$nbrSims <- as.character(data_price$nbrSims)
 data_price$nbrSims <- ifelse(is.na(data_price$nbrSims), 
             'Single', data_price$nbrSims)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to be clear, Marta's answer is right.

You can also change all Na Values with this

```
data_price[is.na(data_price)]<-"Something"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Data$Mileage <- ifelse( is.na(Data$Mileage),
                        median(Data$Mileage, na.rm = TRUE),
                        Data$Mileage)
```

In above code, you can change NA value with the median of the column.